# Looping over a list in Java to check for a value

Tags: java

I have a list of an object

```
List<myObj> myObjList
```

Here, myObj is a class with the following structure:

```
public class myObj {
    private String id;
    private String pwd;
    private String type;
    //Getters/Setters
}
```

I want to loop through the list to check, if i have a particular id. I tried :

```
for (obj : myObjList) {
    if (MY_STRING.equals(obj.getId())) {
        aBooleanFlag = true;
    }
}
```

However, when i want to use, contains method, it is failing. The way i am using it is :

```
if(myObj.contains(MY_STRING)) {
    aBooleanFlag = true;    
}
```

Can you suggest what is wrong and how to fix it

Comment: try  if(myObj.getID().contains(MY_STRING)) {
    aBooleanFlag = true;    
}

Comment: What's wrong with your first version? It needs a `break` statement when you get a match, of course.

Comment: Do you mean myObjList.contains(MY_STRING) instead of myObj.contains(MY_STRING)?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I mean the first thing you said you tried. It's up there in black and white. The loop.

Comment: `myObjList.stream().anyMatch(obj -> obj.getId().equals(MY_STRING))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.contains()` checks whether any object in the list is equal to the parameter.

A `myObj` instance will never equal a `String`.

Comment: thats what i suspect. So is there any other way to loop over the object ? Any sample codes ?

Comment: A `myObj` instance can indeed equal a `String` if its `equals()` method is written appropriately.

Comment: If you want to use contains, you need to create a list of "id"

Comment: @EJP Only if it violates the `equals` contract, since `myObj.equals(str)` and `str.equals(myObj)` would return different things. So, only if its `equals()` method is written *inappropriately*.

Comment: @EJP I agree, I thought you are looking for myObjList.contains(MY_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(myObj.contains(MY_STRING)) {
    aBooleanFlag = true;    
}
```

to

```
if (myObj.getId().contains(MY_STRING)) {
        aBooleanFlag = true;
    }
```

Comment: He wants to check whether he has a particular ID, not whether it is contained within another ID.

Comment: @EJP, then in the loop, use obj.getId().equals(MY_STRING)

Comment: So the better way is that he use equals or equalsIgnoreCase like he wrote in his code

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you use `.equals(Object)`.
If you want to compare 2 String you should use `.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`.
 You als neeed to define what obj is.
So this would be your code:

```
for (Object obj : myObjList) {
    if (MY_STRING.equalsIgnoreCase(obj.getId())) {
        aBooleanFlag = true;
    }
}
```

If you use the if method, you should check if the List contains the String.
Checking if a class contains a String would not help.
So your code there would be:

```
if(myObjList.contains(MY_STRING)) {
    aBooleanFlag = true;    
}
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `String` to an entire `MyObj` object using `equals`. This is like asking whether your car is equal to a hubcap (one part of your car).

You can either iterate over the list:

```
boolean found = false;
for (MyObj obj : myObjList) {
    if (obj.getId().equals(MY_STRING)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can use Java 8 streams with `anyMatch()` and a predicate:

```
boolean found = myObjList.stream().anyMatch(obj -> obj.getId().equals(MY_STRING));
```

Or you can use a `Map` instead of a `List`, and look items up by id:

```
Map<String, MyObj> theMap = new HashMap<>();
// put MyObj's into the map by id
theMap.put(myObj.getId(), myObj);
// check for one using its id
boolean found = theMap.containsKey(MY_STRING);
```

I changed the name of the class from `myObj` to `MyObj` because the convention is that class names start with capital letters in Java.

Answer (score -2):

You should be using a `Map` instead of a `List.`

Comment: You need one more set of parentheses. Also, this violates the *symmetric* clause of the [`equals contract`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)